# Get earliest and latest inserted rows in a table using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this structure...

```
ID  date                Value
732 2019-07-03 15:04:42 283.0
732 2019-07-03 15:24:07 283.2
732 2019-07-03 15:43:44 283.4
732 2019-07-03 16:03:37 283.5
732 2019-07-03 16:22:47 283.7
732 2019-07-03 16:42:25 283.8
733 2019-06-14 13:24:01 226.3
733 2019-06-14 15:09:38 228.1
733 2019-06-17 08:39:59 291.5
733 2019-06-17 10:46:20 291.7
```

I can do a simple select like:

```
select * 
from table 
where id=732 and date < '2019-07-03 16:03:37' 
and date > '2019-07-03 15:24:07'
```

But it gives me the all the data of the specified time range, and I just need to get the row with the earliest DATE and the row with the latest DATE of the selection time range, so, just two rows.

I tried to use MIN and MAX with no success.

Edition: fixing english language mistakes

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have edited the description because I used the english language badly, there's a difference of context between "of" and "with"... Sorry guys!

Answer (score 1):

A simple method uses `union all` and `limit`:

```
(select t.*
 from t
 order by date asc
 limit 1
) union all
(select t.*
 from t
 order by date desc
 limit 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE
    date = (SELECT min(date) FROM TABLE) OR
    date = (SELECT max(date) FROM TABLE)
```

This will output the first and last records (or multiple records if they fall on the same date).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand you want the cell VALUE from first and last date. I think a subquery will suffice your requirement. And I still would count it as a single SQL.

```
SELECT value
FROM table
WHERE date = (SELECT max(date) FROM table)
OR date = (SELECT min(date) FROM table)
```